# How to fix Safari 9.1 issue with transitioning clip-path after checking CSS position?

Tags: jquery, css, safari, css-transitions, clip-path

I'm seeing behavior in Safari 9.1 that appears to be a bug in Safari, but I'm putting it out here to see if it's an issue with my code.

I have a site that is transitioning CSS Shapes polygon clip-paths on user action. It works wonderfully on Chrome 50 but not on Safari. On Safari, the clip-paths stop transitioning when [another plugin](https://github.com/VodkaBears/Vide) uses jQuery to check the CSS position of the element in question.

You can see this behavior in [my pretty minimal codepen](http://codepen.io/GregoryAveryWeir/pen/ZWNxJK) (reproduced below). In Safari, you can click the green triangle to see it animate to fill the page. However, when you click the red triangle, it fails to fill the page even though the only difference is that I check its `$().css('position')`. In Chrome, both triangles work fine.

Is there a way to fix this?

---

HTML:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin: auto;
}

#div1, #div2 {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  transition: clip-path 1s, -webkit-clip-path 1s, width 1s;
}

#div1 {
  background: green;

  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 0 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 0 100%, 0 100%);
}

#div1.active {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

#div2 {
  background: red;

  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

#div2.active {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

JS:

```
$('div').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

console.log($('#div2').css('position'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I'm going with is separating the clip-path and the element I need to do the position evaluation on. I clip-path an outer `div` and let the plugin chew on the inner `div`. I thereby avoid the whole issue.

However, I'd love an answer that doesn't require adding an extra element.